# Do I need Office 2013 & the premium edition for Visual Studio for my development and production environments?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In the following link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15289.sharepoint-2013-best-practices-creating-a-development-environment.aspx it is mentioned that I need to have the following when building my SharePoint 2013 environment:-

1.Office 2013.

2.The premium edition of Visual-Studio 2012.

But my current situation is that I already got Visual-Studio 2012 professional edition based on my previous reading which mentioned that the professional version will have all the required SharePoint templates.
So my questions are:-

1. Do I need the Office 2013 and VS premium?

2.And if yes, then should I have office 2013 on both my production and development environments?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't need** Office 2013 (or any previous version) installed to do any SharePoint Development (unless you want to do Office component integration... within Office)

It's handy to have Office installed on your environment but definitively **not mandatory**. I rarely put it on my VM even when I'm heavily working with collaboration portals.

In similar fashion, you definitively **don't want to install Office 2013 on your production environment** (a server has way better things to receive / handle than Office Client !) but you would benefit from having a **Office Web Application server** attached to your farm if you want your user to see / edit Office assets without having Office installed.

Also you don't need Visual Studio 2012 "Premium". I'm doing all my 2013 development in Visual Studio 2010 Professional but you'll for sure need the RTM edition of the **Office Dev Tools for VS2012** : http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012 since they contains all the nice templates for SP2013 (otherwise you'll only see the SharePoint 2010 templates)

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, since this is my first SharePoint project to implement. but as i know that i still can use the SP2010 templates inside my SP 2013 server ?

Comment: Yupp, but the add on is free and will give you nice addition. You should really install it on the top of your Visual Studio 2012 installation (while we're all waiting for the lovely CKS:DEV extension !)